# id class in objective-c , why is it suitable for any classes?

Tags: objective-c

I have a question about the class `id` in Objective-C. I don't know why it is suitable for any classes, like:

```
id objc = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

I know that `id` class is a pointer to a struct called `objc_object`, but the right of the code return a memory address of an instance, whose size is different from the struct `objc_object`. So why it is ok to do this?

```
typedef struct objc_object *id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory addresses are same size. Even if you use `UILabel * objc = [[UIButton alloc] init];` It works! The benefit of using **KnownClassType** is that compiler (and IDE) casts it and shows it's iterface to you **even before running** the app. But there is no guarantee for the type at runtime. `id` is just `AnyObject` type that you should take care of type casting for it yourself.

Comment: wow amazing! but why??? 
if I create a class called `Children`  contains two int vars(so the size will be 16 bytes), and another class called `Parent` contains one int var(size will be 12 bytes),
is this ok?:
`Children *child = [[Parent alloc] init]`

Comment: Why `id`? Because some times a variable can be more than just `one type`! An example is the `sender` that sends `closeKeyboard` message. It could be a `UIButton` or `Gesture` or `AnyType`.

Comment: I have tried, it is okay to use like this!  but I still can't figure out, isn't the the size of different instances may be different?

Comment: Yes but instances live in the heap! We are talking about pointer **itself** not about what it points to.

Comment: !!!!!! I think I  got it , the `alloc` will return the address of `isa` right?  and any classes 's isa is the same size [link](https://user-gold-cdn.xitu.io/2018/4/7/1629daf2207dedcd?imageView2/0/w/1280/h/960/format/webp/ignore-error/1)

Comment: Sort of. Imagine instance contains meta about type and size of itself and pointer just points to that meta.

Comment: What makes me confused at first is that in C, it's wrong to use like this:
`double * p1 = ....`
`int *p2 = p1`
because p1 and p2 point to different size of memory

Comment: It is completely the same in C. (Actually it *is* C.) `void *ptr` ist suitable for any type. Only dereferencing is impossible.